# Updating a view in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-update, sqlplus

Below, I have defined some tables, for the relevant ones I have typed in the definitions. Pretty simple, though now I'm trying to raise the salaries for those two employees in the view, and I can't complete the update having that error message you will see below. Anyone could guide me a bit, please??
Definitions for tables employees, projects and employees_projects:
create table employee
(
    id number,
    name varchar2(20),
    mobile varchar2(10),
    address varchar2(30),
    salary number(6,2),
    hire_date date,
    department_id number
);

create table project
(
    id number,
    name varchar2(20),
    budget number(10,2),
    start_date date,
    finish_date date
);
create table employee_projects
(
    id number,
    employee_id number,
    project_id number
);

View definition is:

```
create view lucky_employees as 
select e.name,e.salary from employees e, project p, employee_projects ep 
where e.project_id=p.id and e.id=ep.employee_id and p.budget > 1000000.00 ;
```

SQL> select * from lucky_employees;

```
    ID NAME                     SALARY
```

---

```
     1 Maria                   1365.28
     2 Sonja                   1365.28
```

Then, I try to update the view by 10%, which is something I know it's possible to do under certain conditions:
SQL>

```
update lucky_employees set salary = salary * 1.1;
update lucky_employees set salary = salary * 1.1
                       *
```

ERROR at line 1:

```
ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
```

How would it be to succesfully update it??

Thanks very much, sorry for the inconveniences!!

Comment: I think you may need to add the definition of the view.

Comment: Please show the view and the underlying tables.  We are not mind readers.

Comment: I'm trying to read your mind and...(*grunt!*)...(*grrrrrrr*)...(*blink*)...I got nothin'. Instead of counting on our questionable skills at remote mind-reading, you might want to post the `CREATE VIEW` statement **and** the version of Oracle you're using. Might save time, trouble, and a few headaches. Thanks. (And - somebody pass the ibuprofen...)

Comment: OK guys, sorry for the delay, and thank heaps for your responses. The version for my sqlplus is 11.2, and, here's the creation of the view:
create view lucky_employees as
select e.name from 
employees e, project p, employee_projects ep
where e.project_id=p.id
and e.id=ep.employee_id
and p.budget > 1000000.00 ;

Comment: and then, the view is the one above with those two employees. 
The idea is to raise their salary by 10% updating the view like

SQL> update lucky_employees set salary = salary * 1.1;

but I got that error msg: ERROR at line 1: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

thanks!!!!

Comment: It would be useful to have the definitions of the tables as well.  Also, you should edit your question, so that the view definition and table definitions are properly formatted and readable.  As you can see above, you can't really properly edit or format them in the comments.

Comment: add the view definition to the question instead of a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create view lucky_employees as 
select e.name from employees e, project p, employee_projects ep 
where e.project_id=p.id and e.id=ep.employee_id and p.budget > 1000000.00 ;
```

This error is occurring because each salary of your view doesnot uniquely map to a salary of your employees table.

More information from oracle docs is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/views.htm#ADMIN11783).
Anoter explanation from Burleson [here.](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01779_cannot_modify_a_column_which_maps_to_a_non_keypreserved_table.htm)